# How to select an index of an element inside an element of a list of a user's string input separated by comma?

Tags: python, list, indexing

User's input should be a list of full names separated by comma (same input as 2nd code below).
I want to print those names in separate lines in the format of: `lastname  + "," + firstname + middlename` (if applicable).

I have written two codes but I can't seem to bring them together to my desired output:

1st code - Names are sorted as surname + comma + firstnames (includes middlename if given):

```
while True:
    name = input("Enter your full name here:").strip().title()

    words_in_name = name.split()
    surname = words_in_name[-1]
    firstname = words_in_name[:-1]

    name_sorted = surname, " ".join(firstname)

    print(name_sorted)
```

```
Enter your full name here: John Doe
('Doe', 'John')
```

2nd code - List of fullnames are printed in separate lines and comma that separates them in the input are removed:

```
while True: 
    DL_names = input("Enter the list of names you want to add to the DL:").strip().title()

    print(*DL_names.split(","), sep='\n')
```

```
Enter the list of names you want to add to the DL:John Doe, Jane Doe 

 John Doe
  Jane Doe
```

Comment: Please can you indent the code in the question as it appears in your program.

Comment: Also for your info, your statement `name_sorted = surname, " ".join(firstname)` produces a 2-element tuple (just as if you had written parenthesis around the right-hand side).

Comment: Will I need to change the statement in order to make it work properly then? How is the best option to replace the tuple to have the same output (surname, firstnames)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have all pieces of code to make it work. You could make the code a little shorter by assigning `surname` and `firstname` to their respective index of the split string (also you should split on `,` first):

```
DL_names = input("Enter the list of names you want to add to the DL:").strip().title()
for full_name in DL_names.split(','):
    *firstname, surname = full_name.split()
    print(f"{surname}, {' '.join(firstname)}")
```

Output:

```
Doe, John
Doe, Jane
```